# Nest-mqtt closing & reconnecting repeatedly, how to keep it open

Tags: node.js, mqtt, nestjs

The nest-mqtt channel is offline(not staying alive), reconnecting and closing again and again. Is there anything in the Options in @Module that we can set so that it remains open. As I am not able to publish any packet.

**Code in @Module**:

```
MqttModule.forRoot({
  host:'mqtt://xyx.xyx.xyx.xyx',
  port:1234,
  // queue: true,
  share:'group1',
  keepalive: 30000,
  reconnectPeriod: 0,
}),
```

**Output in console**

[Nest] 52   - 01/20/2021, 7:57:47 AM   [MqttModule] MQTT reconnecting

[Nest] 52   - 01/20/2021, 7:57:47 AM   [MqttModule] MQTT closed

[Nest] 52   - 01/20/2021, 7:57:57 AM   [MqttModule] MQTT reconnecting

[Nest] 52   - 01/20/2021, 7:57:57 AM   [MqttModule] MQTT closed

Comment: Repeated connect/disconnect cycling normally means you have 2 clients with the same clientID but in this case I would assume you have the wrong connection details for your broker. Check the broker logs

Comment: If by connection details you mean IP & Port, then I am certain the details are correct since I have used the same in other places. We can assume the IP & port are correct. Also, how does having multiple clients is a problem, doesn't it defeat the purpose of asynchronous messaging.

Comment: I said, multiple clients with the same **clientID**. Client IDs must be unique.

Comment: Also since the field is labelled `host` have you tried without the url schema attached? `host: 'xyx.xyx.xyx.xyx',`?

Comment: Sure will check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hashed out in the comments, the configuration expects a just a hostname/ip address in the `host` field, not a URL

```
MqttModule.forRoot({
  host:'xyx.xyx.xyx.xyx',
  port:1234,
  // queue: true,
  share:'group1',
  keepalive: 30000,
  reconnectPeriod: 0,
}),
```